# How to browse image make it appear in Image control

Tags: asp.net

My Scenario,

I'm using `Visual Studio 2005`. In my website Page I'm trying to browse a image and display in image control and then i need to insert to Database, But I'm Unable to bring the image to control.

1.Browse image
2.View in the control and then insert in Database.
 This What I want and I'm searching for code.

Comment: check this link http://aspalliance.com/140_Retrieving_Images_from_SqlServer_in_ASP_NET

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to do on the client side without sending the image to the server at all without using a technology like Flash to display the preview of the image before uploading it.

If you wish to use Flash, then there is a donationware component called [Agile Uploader](http://www.shift8creative.com/projects/agile-uploader/index.html) that even has a jQuery plugin available that allows you to display a preview of the image wherever you like before uploading, as well as being able to resize the image on the client side first, so you don't have users uploading massive files. It's well worth a look.